# Force minimum number of rows in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I wish to force my Listview to show a minimum number of rows.

In other words, if there are only 3 rows in the data I still want to show 8 rows on the screen. I will ensure in getView that the correct data is returned for the empty rows.

I tried overriding getCount()

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return Math.min(NUM_OF_ITEMS_DISPLAYED,SearchableListScreen.this._results.size());
}
```

But when I put "Log" entries into my getView I see that it only gets called for the rows that originally exist in my data and now for the extra rows.
Is there any way to do it other than actually adding dummy rows to my data?

Comment: Blah. Just noticed my mistake. Should be Math.max!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

always have atleast 8 entries in your `List` or `Array` of entries which you use to populate the `ListView` with. That way you'll have at least 8 rows.